# Netty 3.2.6 to Netty 4.0x migration

Tags: java, migration, version, netty

I have following specific queries on migration

a) I am currently using `IdleStateAwareChannelUpstreamHandler` to handle `channelIdle` event along with other regular `ChannelUpstream` event callbacks. When this is migrated to 4.0x model, what should be the equivalent approach ?

b) What is the equivalent `EventExecutor` for `OrdredMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` in 4.0x ?

c) In 3.2.6, I had used channelId from event objects of handler-callbacks to keep track of clients uniquely. For example, in `channelConnected` callback, I used to obtain the `channelId` from `evt.getChannel().getId()`. Since events are more fine-grained in 4.0x, what is the best way to obtain Netty-generated unique channel id ? I had checked if `ChannelHandlerContext` provides a means to obtain the same. But I could not find an equivalent

I am referring to javadocs at http://netty.io/4.0/api/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) See the javadocs of the IdleStateHandler. You need to intercept IdleStateEvents in the userEventTriggered(..) method.

b) specify a EventExecutor when adding a ChannelHandler to the ChannelPipeline. See [No more `ExecutionHandler` - it's in the core.](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/New-and-noteworthy-in-4.0#no-more-executionhandler---its-in-the-core)

c) There is currently no id() on the Channel anymore. You can use Channel.hashCode() for now. Most likely the id() will come back in a later release.

Comment: Thanks Norman. I will take a closer look at the EventExecutor as to how it ensures order